# Нужна ли запятая перед "ближе"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Собрав и подготовив людей, их отправили для оказания первой помощи раненным в бою ближе к фронту.

Comment: Первую помощь оказывают на месте, то есть на фронте, а не "ближе к фронту". Не так ли?

Comment: Первую помощь даже недалеко от фронта оказывать затруднительно, а "на фронт" отправляют обычно воевать. Поэтому лучше выбрать нейтральный вариант: "отправили на линию фронта".

Comment: ... Процесс лечения разделяется на от­дельные виды помощи оказываемой на поле боя (пер­вая помощь, доврачебная помощь) и в медицинских подразделениях, частях, учреждениях (первая врачеб­ная помощь, квалифицированная и специали­зированная медицинская помощь, медицинская реа­билитация). (Наставление по оказанию первой помощи раненым и больным,  http://spec-naz.org/preparation/spetsialnaya_meditsinskaya_podgotovka/1443nastavlenije_po_okazaniju_pervoj_pomoshhi_ranenym_i_bolnym/)

Comment: Первая помощь оказывается, как правило, на месте получения ранения (поражения) или развития заболевания в порядке самопомощи (оказывает сам пострадавший) и взаимопомощи (оказывает това­рищ), а также санитарами и санитарами-стрелками. Для ее оказания используются преимущественно ин­дивидуальные средства медицинского оснащения. (Там же)

Comment: Есть подозрение, что выражение "раненный в бою" является в данном контексте плеоназмом (и так понятно, что в бою).

Answer (score 1):

В предложении нужно изменить порядок слов:

Вариант 1. **Собрав и подготовив людей, их отправили ближе к фронту для оказания первой помощи раненным в бою.** Неоднородные обстоятельства.

Вариант 2.  **Собрав и подготовив людей, их отправили ближе к фронту, для оказания первой помощи раненным в бою.** При наличии уточнения.

Comment: Если убрать "в бою", то надо писать "для оказания первой помощи раненым", одна буква Н.

Comment: Вас неправильно информировали. Количество Н определяется тем, считаь ли слово прилагательным или причастием. А этот выбор определяется тем, присутсвует ли глагольное значение, другими словами постоянный ли признак тут или состояние. так вот в большинстве случаев даже в у одиночного причастия "раненный" глагольность сохраняется.   Розенталь: https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1015483/67/Rozental_-_Spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu%2C_proiznosheniyu%2C_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu.html (пункт 4.)

Comment: В данном предложении это существительное. Из словаря: РАНЕНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Имеющий рану, получивший ранение. Р. боец. Р. лось. Р-ая рука. <Раненый, -ого; м. Привезли РАНЕНЫХ. Перевязать РАНЕНОГО.

Comment: *В данном предложении это существительное* - не вижу внятного обоснования. Розенталь  (по ссылке): *Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выяснение вопроса о написании нн — н) иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому. Например, в предложении "Будучи раненным,  солдат оставался в строю" слово "раненный" — причастие и пишется с двумя н,..*. Это как раз наш случай. Причастие, сохранившее признак состояния, а не свойства.

Comment: И вообще: поменьше ссылайтесь на Кузнецова в таких вопросах. Он путаник великий, но даже он не назівает прилагательное существительным.

Comment: https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/350152.html РАНЕНЫЙ ра́неный 1. м. Тот, кто получил ранение. 2. прил. Имеющий рану (1), получивший ранение.  http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1416987-ranenyj-eto-imja-suschestvitelnoe-ili-prilagatelnoe.html

Comment: а что и как ваш копипаст доказывает?! Я не люблю ссылки на разный треп, но так получилось, что на грамоте синхронно начали обсуждать тот же вопрос. Посмотрите, даже там, на форуме известном безапелляционностью участников, никто так категорично вопрос не ставит. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=6612

Comment: Повторюсь. Мое мнение, что во всех примерах, подобном разбираемому, состояние превалирует над признаком. Поэтому причастие. Прилагательное безусловно вписывается только в качестве субстантивированного *(палата для раненых, раненые отправлены в медсанбат - и проч.)*. В иных случаях "раненный" если не предпочтительно, то как минимум допустимо.

Comment: Обоснование такое. Мы выбираем между причастием (НН)  и прилагательным (Н), если есть определяемое слово. Если его нет, то это существительной (одна буква Н).

Comment: *Обоснование такое* - Ой...Вы, еще существительное здесь  вспомнив, окончательео все смешали. Но даже закрывая глаза на внутреннюю путаницу...  Вы запутались в причинно-следственной связи. вам как раз и надо бы обосновать, ***почему вы считаете наличие зависимого слова неким критерием***. На самом деле это всего лишь некая запоминалка весьма сомнительного круга  действия, она не раскрывает суть разницы между причастием и прилагательным. Но это ладно...Как вы объясните то, что Розенталь напрочь отвергает такой подход?!

Comment: Я не о зависимом слове говорю, а об ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕМОМ: (1) оказать помощь РАНЕНЫМ СОЛДАТАМ, глагольная форма определяет существительное; (2) оказать помощь РАНЕНЫМ, при отсутствии существительного глагольная форма  сама становится существительным.

Answer (score 0):

*Собрав и подготовив людей, их отправили — для оказания первой помощи раненным в бою — ближе к фронту.*

Так можно (выделив с помощью тире вводный оборот) обозначить неразрывность слов «отправили ближе к фронту».

Answer (score 0):

Мотивы для запятой понятны и они разумны: надо как-то отделить уточнение от уточняемого. Но вся беда в том, что фразу надо переделывать, одна пунктуация здесь не спасет.

Во-первых, в исходном варианте получается "раненных ближе к фронту" - это что-то фантастическое. Во-вторых, "раненных в бою" здесь излишне, речь же не идет о каком-то конкретном бое, одного которого ради собирали людей.

Проще всего так:
***Собрав и подготовив людей, их отправили ближе к фронту для оказания первой помощи раненным.***
Тут запятые при "ближе к фронту" не нужны.

Хотя даже в таком виде фраза не блещет высоким стилем из-за деепричастия при неопределенно-личной конструкции, формально это грамматикой разрешено, особенно в разговорной речи.

*Другое дело, что есть некое сомнение в правильности понимания, кто там кого и зачем отправлял. Первая помощь, как верное замечено, оказывается прямо на поле боя, часто даже во время боя. С другой стороны, не отправлять же санитаров в бой? Скорее всего имелась в виду **прифронтовая** зона, где и размещаются собственно санитарные подразделения. Но это уже вопросы фактического соответствия текста, не пунктуации и даже не стилистики... Тут разбираться с ними затруднительно.*

Comment: И все-таки. Не думаю, что удвоенное *н* тут уместно. Поск в Нацкпрпусе дает: помощь *раненым* — 41, помощь *раненным* — 1, и то  1874 года.

Comment: @М_Г - здесь количеством ничего не докажешь. Скорее всего в огромном большинстве случаев там субстантиват. Но посмотрю позже.